# ColdFusion 9 ORM "LEFT JOIN" in Join Mapping

Tags: hibernate, orm, coldfusion, left-join, hibernate-mapping

It's been a while since I last used the Hibernate implementation in CF9 and right now I'm at a point where I can't see the woods for all the trees (probably not enough coffee).

I've simplified the example to make it more relatable, but the nature of the problem is the same (join mapping in multi-table components should allow for optional relationships).

Inside my user component I have the following property to include the email address, which is stored in a separate table.

```
<cfproperty name="sEmail" 
   type="string" 
   default="" 
   table="UserEmail" 
   joincolumn="fkUserID" 
   inversejoincolumn="pkUserID" />
```

Unfortunately this generates an INNER JOIN whereas I'd like a LEFT JOIN so an entry in the other table wouldn't be mandatory to retrieve/persist an entity.

So my question is:
**What attribute is necessary to turn this from mandatory (e.g., INNER JOIN) into optional (e.g., LEFT OUTER JOIN)?**

Google results were flooded with HQL-related examples, which made that option mostly unusable.

Thanks in advance for your replies.

*Added later:*

Hibernate itself has an "optional" attribute for that ( http://www.scribd.com/doc/2732589/Hibernate-Reference-Documentation#outer_page_74 ), but there doesn't seem to be a straight translation into CF's attributes. But maybe there's still a chance someone else might know a way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's a way through hibernate. I would be suprised if there would be a way. In this situations, I would normally populate the variable manually with a custom query within a custom function (i.e. loadSEmail()).

Comment: That could be done through a mere formula, but that wouldn't integrate the property deep enough so it's automatically included in the insert/update process without having to use a custom method.